# Pass javascript variable to twig

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, symfony, twig

I just want to pass a javascript variable to a twig path. Now i'm using this, but it doesn't work.

```
<p id="result"></p>
<script>
var text = "";
var i;
for (varJS = 0; varJS < 5; varJS++) {
    text += "<a href='{{ path('lesson',{'id': varJS }) }}'>article</a>";
}
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = text;
</script>
```

Comment: do you mean variable value here?

Comment: yeah , the varJS vallue

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
for (varJS = 0; varJS < 5; varJS++) {
    var url = '{{ path("lesson", {'id': 'article_id'}) }}'; 
    url = url.replace("article_id", varJS);
    text += '<a href='+ url +'>article</a>';
}
```

**Note** You should really look at the [FOSJsRoutingBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle).

Comment: Thanks , that's really what i need :)

Comment: Glad to help you @hassenzouari

Comment: you are really the best bro :)

Answer (score 2):

According to Chalasr's answer.

I've done this thrick using :

```
<script>
  var your_js_variable = 5;
  `{{ path("deletePFTaxeSpeciale",{'id' : 'idCarburant' }) }}`.replace('idCarburant', your_js_variable)
<script>
```