# Using ajax call result in twig path function

Tags: php, ajax, symfony, twig

I am using twig and symfony 2.8. In a twig template I make an AJAX call to a php script. this is the simplified AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'{{ (path('search')) }}',
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        "fields": {
            "invoiceNo" : $("#invoiceNo").val()
        }
    },
    async: true,
    success: function (data)
    {

    }
});
```

The response `data` is an array containing the id of some invoices. I want to use the path function in twig to generate urls of invoices based on the IDs in `data`.

I did this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var url = {{ path('invoice_url', {'invoiceId' : data[i]['id']}) }}
}
```

However I am getting an error that the variable data does not exist. I suppose, this is because data is a runtime variable.

any idea how I can use AJAX call result (`data`) to generate the urls?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass javascript variable to twig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36291358/pass-javascript-variable-to-twig)

Comment: @goto I'm not sure the question you linked answers this question; this question is about how to use the result of an Ajax call in Twig

Comment: This isn't possible; Twig, like PHP, is executed server-side while the Ajax call is handled entirely client-side. It's possible to find a workaround using only JS and jQuery, but you won't be able to use Twig in that way. You can also check out [FOSJsRoutingBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle) on GitHub

Comment: @goto This is not a duplicate of what you mentioned. Here data is  generated at run time. and not a fixed value.

Comment: You can't pass javascript variable to twig (PHP)

If you want to generate a route in javascript, you can either replace a flag in your route by javascript, or use [FOSJsRoutingBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle). 

As answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36291358/pass-javascript-variable-to-twig

Comment: How is this possible a question about the result of an ajax call, as your ajax call is never called? Goto is correct in here, that u'd need to use `FOSJSRoutingBundle` to resolve the `url` to where u want to post your `ajax`-call