# How do I pass the Id of the element from my DataTable into my button using jQuery/Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Currently, I have the button passing the entire row, but I only need the Id. Is there an easy way for me to just extract the Id of the element in the table?

This is the DataTable code:

```
 <div>
        <table id="allAccounts" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Organization</th>
                    <th>State</th>
                    <th>Actions</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody></tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

These are the jQuery/Ajax scripts:

```
@section Scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#allAccounts').DataTable(
                {
                    "responsive": true,
                    "ajax": {
                        "url": "/api/User/GetUsers",
                        "dataSrc": ""

                    },
                    "columns": [
                        { "data": "FirstName" },
                        { "data": "LastName" },
                        { "data": "Organization" },
                        { "data": "State" },
                        {
                            "data": "Id",
                            "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
                                return "<button class='btn btn-primary' style=margin-right:5px; onclick=ViewUser(" + JSON.stringify(row) + ")>View Details</button>" +
                                    "<button class='btn btn-danger' style=margin-right:5px; onclick=DeleteUser(" + JSON.stringify(row) + ")>Delete</button>"

                            }
                        }
                    ]
                });
        });
        function ViewUser(data) {
            $.ajax({
                "type": "POST",
                "url": "/api/UpdateUser",
                "data": data,
                "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8"

            })
        }
        function DeleteUser(data) {
            $.ajax({
                "type": "POST",
                "url": "/api/User/Delete",
                "data": data,
                "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
            })
        }
    </script>
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Depending on the "shape" of your data you could replace `JSON.stringify(row)` with `row.id`.

Comment: Here is what you wanted

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36291358/pass-javascript-variable-to-twig

Answer (score 0):

An approach is to give the button a new identifying class> We can remove the hard code on the buttons. Then add a listener for a button click.

Let's say your HTML for a table row is something like this when rendered...

```
<tr>
    <td>Joan</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>Unknown</td>
    <td>Perplexed</td>
    <td data-id='123'>
        <button class='btn btn-primary btn-view' style=margin-right:5px;>View Details</button>
        <button class='btn btn-danger btn-delete' style=margin-right:5px;>Delete</button>"
    </td>
</tr>
```

And so the listener becomes

```
$('body').on('click', '.btn-view', function(e){

    // get the data from the parent TD of the clicked button
    var id = $(this).parent().data('data-id');

    $.ajax({
        "type": "POST",
        "url": "/api/UpdateUser",
        "data": id,
        "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8"

    })
}
```

Notes:

1. I have cut corners on passing the id in the ajax() call - I'll leave
   you to solve that.
2. The on click format uses event delegation -
   effectively meaning the ultimate parent (body) is listening for the
   event to bubble up thus making a more efficient listener than if we
   put one on every button in a long table.  See Event delegation:
   https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/
3. You can take the
   same approach for the delete button.
4. You will save a decent amount of bandwidth cutting out the repeated
   code in the actions cells.